# PostgreSQL - non-aggregated fields to be present in the GROUP BY clause -Alternative method

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I need to get a result by joining around 10 tables in Postgresql but need to group the result by one table's primary key.

Is there any method to build the query without including those unwanted fields in the `group by` clause other than the **recursive query**(sub query execution)?

My query is as shown below:

```
select cd.closedroomid, cd.mongoid as _id, 'close' as type,
count(r.reviewid) as "reviewsCount", h.mongoid as "hospitalityId",
h.hospitalityname as name, 
fMain.mongoid as "mainImage",
fUnique.mongoid as "uniqueImage", 
string_agg(fFotovan.mongoid, ',') as "fotovanImage",
string_agg(fFoodAndDrinks.mongoid, ',') as "foodAndDrinksImage",
h.parkingPricePerHour, h.parkingPricePerDay, 0 as "flexWorkspaceCount",
'' AS favourites,
h.averagefoodprice, 
string_agg(fImages.mongoid, ',') as imageIds, 
case when bs.bookable = 'direct' then true else false end as isBookableDirect,
case when bd.bookingdiscountid IS NULL then false else true end as bookingDiscount
from table1 h
inner join table2 cd 
on cd.hospitalityid = h.hospitalityid
LEFT JOIN table3 r
on r.workspacetype = 'close' and r.closedroomid = cd.closedroomid
and r.hospitalityid = h.hospitalityid
LEFT JOIN files fMain
on fMain.filerelationfromid = h.hospitalityid and fMain.filerelationfrom = 'hospitality'
and fMain.ismainimage = true
LEFT JOIN files fUnique
on fUnique.filerelationfromid = h.hospitalityid and fUnique.filerelationfrom = 'hospitality'
and fUnique.isuniqueimage = true
LEFT JOIN files fFotovan
on fFotovan.filerelationfromid = h.hospitalityid and fFotovan.filerelationfrom = 'hospitalityOutside'
LEFT JOIN files fFoodAndDrinks
on fFoodAndDrinks.filerelationfromid = h.hospitalityid and fFoodAndDrinks.filerelationfrom = 'foodAndDrinks'
LEFT JOIN files fImages
on fImages.filerelationfromid = h.hospitalityid and fImages.filerelationfrom = 'hospitality'
and fImages.isuniqueimage != true and fImages.ismainimage != true
LEFT JOIN bookingslots bs 
on bs.closedroomid = cd.closedroomid
LEFT JOIN bookingdiscountclosedroomrel bdcr
on bdcr.closedroomid = cd.closedroomid
LEFT JOIN bookingdiscounts bd
on bd.bookingdiscountid = bdcr.bookingdiscountid AND bd.status = 'Valid'
where h.isdeleted = false  
group by cd.closedroomid, h.hospitalityid, fMain.fileid, fUnique.fileid, 
fFotovan.fileid, fFoodAndDrinks.fileid, fImages.fileid, bs.bookingslotid,
bd.bookingdiscountid;
```

Here Actually I want the result to be grouped by only the `cd.closedroomid`. But postgresql is not allowing without adding all the other non aggregated fields to be specified in the **group by** clause.

The simple query itself is not executing without including all the fields in the group by clause.

```
select cd.closedroomid, cd.mongoid as _id, 'close' as type,
h.mongoid as "hospitalityId", h.hospitalityname as name, 
h.parkingPricePerHour, h.parkingPricePerDay, 0 as "flexWorkspaceCount", '' AS favourites, h.averagefoodprice
from table1 cd 
inner join table2 h 
on cd.hospitalityid = h.hospitalityid
where cd.isactive = true and h.isdeleted = false   
group by cd.closedroomid
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Please add 1) the table structure 2) some data sample and 3) the exact expected result. Since we're talking about 10 tables, it would be better if you create a minimal example.

Comment: @JimJones. Thanks for the reply. Added the query.

Comment: You could put the `count(r.reviewid)` into a scalar subquery.

Comment: Even if the count(r reviewid) is not present in the select param, the query is not executing without including the other fields in the group by clause.